# Indexing triple nested List to assign new values in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, nested-loops, nested-lists

I need help understanding how to update the colors of specific data points in a triple nested list in Python. As it stands, the nested for loop is updating the data points for all axes in with the new color of the most recently called axis each time, so the x and y axis colors are identical despite having different data points. I need some help catching what is wrong in this loop.

```
xColors=['#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999','#999999']
yColors=xColors

xData=inputtedData['X Values'] #Series imported from spreadsheet
xData=xData.tolist()
yData=inputtedData['Y Values'] #Series imported from spreadsheet
yData=yData.tolist()

x=[xData,xColors]
y=[yData,yColors]
data=[x,y]

for axis in range(len(data)):
  for indexData in range(0,72):
    if data[axis][0][indexData]==0:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color0
    elif data[axis][0][indexData]==1:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color1
    elif data[axis][0][indexData]==2:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color2
    elif data[axis][0][indexData]==3:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color3
    elif data[axis][0][indexData]==4:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color4
    elif data[axis][0][indexData]==5:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color5 
    elif data[axis][0][indexData]==6:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color6
    elif data[axis][0][indexData]==7:
        data[axis][1][indexData]=color7
```

Comment: It's not in the for loop and the error can't be reproduced from the given amount of information.

Comment: Just figured out an error earlier in the code, thank you!